# "Allow USB debugging" keeps on popping up

Tags: usb-debugging, automation, developer-options

We are doing automation testing on mobile devices with Appium, but the testing fails because of the popup 'Allow USB debugging?' even though the device is already connected through `adb connect` and `adb devices`.

[image]

I already checked the 'Always allow from this computer', but still, sometimes it pops up and causes the test to fail, and other times it works just fine; not popping up at all.

How to address this issue?

Answer (score 6):

#### Change the USB cable

My proposed solution is not general, but may work in in some special cases.

Here is my story: Once I used an old USB cable for connecting my 10 smartphones to my computer. It worked well for 9 phones, except for 1 phone where “Allow USB debugging” kept on popping. Then I changed to a newer USB cable, and the problem went away.

Comment: I was getting this every few minutes. I switched to a different USB cable and haven't gotten it in a couple of days. We'll see if it lasts but definitely worth a quick shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was continually getting prompted with one fingerprint. I revoked all debugging permissions and next time the dialog popped up, I noticed the fingerprint had changed. So far I haven't been prompted again.

So: try revoking all debug permissions and then allowing USB debugging again.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility for this problem may be located on PC side: May be you are running multiple adb daemons with different private keys. The private key is used for identifying the "**this computer**".

The relevant files that contain the cryptographic identify are `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` located in the folder `.android` folder within the user home directory:

- Windows: `C:\users\%username%\.android\`
- Linux: `~/.android/`

Make sure those two files don't change. Some other software may overwrite these files.

Another possibility would be a problem on device side that e.g. the adb server crashes and losses the data on previous authorized computers. Or it may be a bug in adb that causes the identification of the computer to fail.

Comment: Problem with the USB port or the the cable can also does that. It used to be the case with  my Nexus 6 (bad port, bad cable) but this is unlikely the case for OP though.

Comment: Thank you @Robert for this one. I will sure to check it on my side. But i am using my pc that is connected to the mobile device with a usb cable. Regarding on the another possibility, should i have a checker to check every execution whether the RSA key of the computer is already authorized to the mobile device then add it otherwise?

Comment: Yes @Firelord, I also think that it may be because of the usb cable that caused the loss of connection but I have a checker to execute adb devices to check if there's a connection before executing the test. It says that it is connected but it will fail in creating the mobile capabilities in Appium. So that's what I am wondering about as to why it failed when it says that it is already connected. Then it also prompts the 'Allow usb debugging' even though I already checked the 'Always allow in this computer'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the cable is fully plugged on both ends. On computer side it was a bit loose. It solved the problem.