# Permanent ADB RSA-key authorization

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, broken-screen

My phone screen is broken but I managed to finally tap the allow button for ADB authorization so I can access the device via ADB.

My question:
Is there a way to do this once and never be asked again or backup the RSA which I can then push to the device via ADB if it happens to need re-authorization again (since I have a broken screen I just can't tap allow again).

I have enabled do not ask again on this device, but that does not seem to work from past experience and it keeps asking me to authorize if I reboot the phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Allow USB debugging" keeps on popping evene when "Always allow from this computer" is checked in automation testing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207798/allow-usb-debugging-keeps-on-popping-evene-when-always-allow-from-this-comput)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android ADB Key Not Working](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226666/android-adb-key-not-working)

Comment: @alecxs But scrcpy depends on adb for uploading the file that is executed. Hence it can't be used to control the phone before adb authorization has been set. But afterwards  it would be also by preferred way to control a phone with a broken screen.

Comment: @alecxs Hey thanks for the links, the second one kinda helped but not really, I managed to backup the keys and use scrcpy but then it just disconnected in a second and now we are back to adb authorization prompt even though I had authorised it an hour ago. :(

Comment: Though I had managed to get apowermirror/tea,viewer working but none of those let me unlock the device, it just shows a black screen sadly.

Comment: scrcpy comes with it's own adb binary, that might have caused it. restore the backup and try again. i can hardly imagine that coincidence the keys expired just now

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for all the help, I finally managed to get it to work. The restore method worked. As long as it holds for a couple weeks then I'll receive the new screen to replace the broken one.