# Why does my phone occasionally prompt a new RSA key fingerprint for my computer?

Tags: adb

I use ADB on my Linux PC to do stuff, but sometimes when I connect my phone, it reports an RSA key for my computer to be verified, despite I check the "remember this computer..." every time it had popped up.

I have no idea why this is happening but as far as I know, I had nothing changed regarding it, no updates on my PC, neither on my phone, so this looks very suspicious to me.

Can someone please shed a light on it? This happens roughly once a week or month I had several sessions in this period.

Additional details:

This is happening on my phone running android 9.0.0.

I ran the `stat` command against private and public key files. The birth date for both was more than one year ago, access date and time for the private key was when I got the prompt on the phone. So I suspect that the phone forgets the trusted devices.

There is no timeout option available per [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/226669)  (it applies to 11+ anyway? ). There is though a "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" available but it doesn't show any list or a useful trace.

Comment: it's a security feature you can disable in developer options

Comment: @alecxs ty, but then if it has the option to trust and remember the computer why does it ask again when connected to the same computer? Is this also a separate feature?

Comment: Possible dupe: ["Allow USB debugging" keeps on popping up](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207798/44325)

Comment: How often does the ADB authorization popup occur? Daily, weekly monthly? Which Android version is installed o the phone?

Comment: @Robert 7 days I guess :) https://android.stackexchange.com/a/226669

Comment: @Robert Updated the question with more details IMHO I'm not sure if it's random or not (the vendor is Samsung) but I don't have this problem with my older Sony which runs Android 8.0.0.

Comment: search your PC for multiple `adb` binaries *'find ${PATH//:/ } $HOME -type f -perm /111 -name adb 2> /dev/null'*

Comment: @alecxs There was only one binary, not in the path, (in /lib/android...) and a symlink to that (found with -type l). did even a broader search `find / -type f -name adb 2>/dev/null` and only one adb binary was found.

Comment: do a backup of ~/.android and compare adbkey.pub next time it happened